# Is the derivative in $C(\overline{\Omega})$?

Tags: functions, continuity, solution-verification

> > Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a bounded domain and consider $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$. I would like to know if then
> >     $$
> > 1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\in C(\overline{\Omega})?
> > $$

My answer is: YES, because:

1) $f(x):=1$ is of course uniformly continious on $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it is Lipschitz-continious on whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ then on $\overline{\Omega}$, too, i.e. $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$

2) Because of $u\in C^2(\Omega)$, the partial derivative $u_x$ is uniformly continious on $\Omega$. And a uniformly continious function on a bounded domain can be continued to a continious function $g$ on $\overline{\Omega}$. So $u_x\in C(\Omega)$.

And the sum of two functions on $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is again in $C(\overline{\Omega})$

---

This is my argumentation. Is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

By definition, $u\in C^2(\Omega)\Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\in C(\Omega)$, but $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ may not be uniformly continuous on $\Omega$.

**Counter-example:** $\Omega=(0,1)\times (0,1)$, $u(x,y)=\sqrt{x}$.